# Is there a way in SQL to format a decimal so the negative decimal is displayed in parenthesis

Tags: sql, formatting, decimal

I'm inserting a message into a table that says something like:

```
The old amount of 10.00 is changed to new amount of -20.00.
```

Is there a way to format it, so when inserted into a table it is displayed as

```
The old amount of 10.00 is changed to new amount of ($20.00)
```

So, the formatting formats negative numbers and not positive.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and formatting functions are very different between vendors. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: The answer is very database specific. Please specify the database engine you are using: Oracle, DB2, Sybase, MySQL, etc.

Comment: What about simply using a `case` statement? `select case when amount < 0 then '(' || abs(amount) || ')' else '' || amount || '' end as amount_visual`

Comment: I found the solution, exactly with `case` statements

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is following:

```
'The old amount of ' 
+ CASE WHEN @OldAmount >= 0 THEN CAST(@OldAmount AS VARCHAR) ELSE '($' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ABS(@OldAmount), 106) + ')' END
+ ' is changed to new amount of ' + CASE WHEN @NewAmount >= 0 THEN CAST(@NewAmount AS VARCHAR) ELSE '($' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ABS(@NewAmount), 106) + ')' END
```